# NSPrintOperation rotate image in Landscape print

Tags: objective-c, macos, printing

I am using NSPrintOperation with NSView for printing. I draw an image of my design in my NSView class.

Portrait pages are print well, but when i print in landscape mode the image rotates 90 degree. So Landscape printing not done properly please help me for this.

```
NSPrintOperation* printOperation = [NSPrintOperation 
printOperationWithView: my_print_view printInfo: printInfo];

[[printOperation printInfo] setPaperSize:printInfo.paperSize];

[[printOperation printInfo] setOrientation: NSPaperOrientationLandscape];

[printOperation setCanSpawnSeparateThread: YES];
[printOperation setShowsPrintPanel: NO];

[printOperation runOperationModalForWindow:window delegate: window didRunSelector: nil contextInfo: nil]
```

And in NSView I draw an image like this

```
[design_image drawInRect: image_dr_rct fromRect: NSZeroRect
                                 operation: NSCompositeCopy fraction: 1.0];
```

I think so `NSPrintOperation` graphic context affect my print view design. When i print in landscape page my design also rotate.

Comment: Nobody can tell exactly what you mean by "Landscape printing not done properly."

Comment: thanks to guide me, i m new on this forum. please check it now.